# discover eth0 after boot

Tags: linux, ethernet

On my embedded system I have an Ethernet PHY which is normally in reset state. There's a GPIO driven by the processor for the reset signal.

If I bypass the driver on board and force the PHY in Non-Reset state, I can use the Ethernet link without problem.

Now, I want to let the PHY in reset for normal purpose and activate it only for debugging or technical support. Then when linux is booting, Eth0 is not discovered and I have none Ethernet connection.

I can drive the reset pin to inhibit it. At this stage, I can see on my switch that the corresponding led begin to blink => the PHY is now active.
But I cannot manage to get Eth0 to be populated in my Linux. What shall I do ?

I unsuccessfully tried these so far :
 - looking at ethtool options, it wants a "DEVNAME" for all options
 - restarting systemd-netword services

infos :

> **cat /proc/version**
>   Linux version 4.16.0 (aurelien@l2.lf) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Buildroot 2018.05-gceaa096)) #86 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 3 15:16:32 CEST 2018

Comment: Do you know what driver it uses? You might be able to rmmod the driver module and modprobe it again. Do you know what pci device it is? You might be able to provoke a reset on it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to mount my driver. I need to bind it with the ethernet node of the device tree :

> echo -n "ff702000.ethernet" > /sys/devices/platform/soc/ff702000.ethernet/subsystem/drivers/socfpga-dwmac/bind